# Select - post values?

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to post both a select options value and it's content:

```
 <option value="post this">post this too</option>
```

Comment: yes you can do it for example with javascript and ajax.

Comment: Just with PHP after submitting the form? No. Why just not using same values for both?

Comment: Or another solution is to handle submit() event in javascript and the content to value with separator and after that submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through HTML alone. You could do it with JQuery and some Ajax.

Example:

```
var optionValue = $("#yourSelectId").val();
var optionText = $("#yourSelectId option[value='" + optionValue + "']").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only with Javascript

**JQUERY Example:**

```
<form id="myform">
 <select><option value="post this">post this too</option></select>
</form>


$("#myform").submit(function (){
   $("#myform select option).each(function (element){
       $(element).val($(element).val() + '||' + $(element).text());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the content, you can post with PHP. For the value, I recommend this JavaScript:

```
function getValue()
{
var value = document.getElementById("optionid").value;
return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input which will be populated with selected text from select control, for this you can use for example onchange event to which you will attach a javascript method.